# Filter List of objects using java 8 | Filter on child objects | Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want list of persons who has the valid offer voucher i.e it should satisfy the condition
`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` between `offerStartDate` and `offerEndDate`. Can you tell me how I can achieve this using java 8?

```
class Person {
    private int id;
    private  String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<BankAccounts> listOfAccounts;
    
    //Getter and Setter
}

class BankAccounts {
    
    private String bankName;
    private String IFSC;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<OfferVoucher> offers;
    //Getter and Setter
    
}

class OfferVoucher {
    int amount;
    Date offerStartDate;
    Date offerEndDate;
    //other entities
    //setter and getter
}
```

Comment: Why are your `offerStartDate` and `offerEndDate` `String`s and not a date class like `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` or ....

Comment: it was kept as string "2020-02-09" in this format. I know this should be of type date but is there any way we can covert and compare ?

Comment: You could probably use `LocalDate.parse()` for this, and then `LocalDate.now().isAfter(startDate) && LocalDate.now().isBefore(endDate)` in your filter condition

Comment: ok. Assume the offerStartDate and offerEndDate has valid date datatype. Will you be able to fllter and provide solution

Comment: I suggest you to first write the filtering in the "old-fashioned" way, e.g. using normal `if-else` statements and `for` loops. Then you can quite easily convert that to `Stream`s

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Person> validPersons = persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getListOfAccounts().stream()
            .map(BankAccounts::getOffers)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .allMatch(o -> o.getOfferStartDate() < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP && o.getOfferEndDate() > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I understand the question correctly, this should work. You might want to use `anyMatch` instead of `allMatch`, depending on what you want exactly. I also have handled dates as `Long`, so you may have to update this part, based on your application and how you implement it.

Comment: `o.getOfferStartDate() < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will not work because the `<` or `>` are not defined for `String`s (or any other not primitive numerical type)

Comment: Should we use System class methods instead CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer because of this. I did not handle them as String, because I don't know the format used to store them as String, so I considered them as `Long`. For Strings, `o.getOfferStartDate().compareTo(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) && CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.compareTo(o.getOfferEndDate())` might work.

Comment: It depends on the format of your date stored in Strings, really. The code in my edit will check if the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP String is alphabetically between your dates, which may or may not be a good policy in your situation. If it doesn't work, transform your Strings to Dates, so it would be easy to compare them with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: I have modified the datatype for dates and did some modification to your logic. Created Date todayDate=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();  and to your existing logic .allMatch(o ->todayDate.after(o.getOfferStartDate()) && todayDate.before(o.getOfferEndDate()).but this is not working

Comment: `allMatch` means that it will return all the Persons with all their bank accounts' offers being currently active. If you want to get Persons with at least one of the offers active, then you need to use `anyMatch` instead of `allMatch`. For your dates, check that they are correct.

Comment: This return an empty list even though the offers are available. i.e current date is between offerStart and offerEnd date

Comment: @Mamie could you please help me to figure out the issue

Comment: How is you stream supposed to work ? Do you need all offers to be triggered for the person to be retrieved, or only a single active offer should validated the person?